# Bootstrap burger nav menu not opening in mobile browser

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap stylesheets.

The following code is for my navigation panel. This works fine on my desktop browser but when I reduce the browser size or test on a mobile device, the burger menu appears but does not expand to display the contents of the navigation as expected.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css'>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand color-me" href="#home">Home</a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#about-me">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="##">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="##">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- container -->
  </nav>
```

Am I missing something in my HTML? I don't understand where the problem is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please include this line and will work .

Note: Include in this order - include Jquery before Bootstrap.Bootstrap need Jquery to be loaded before Bootstrap.

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

you are missing the javascript library so that the event isnot responded ,

Answer (score 1):

Seem that you missed include bootstrap js file. Please check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/

Answer (score 1):

I guess using the bootstrap.min.js for the issues won't solve the problem until and unless you do not include the jquery in bootstrap@3

please also include the following link or get it through dist folder of javascript

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```